# How to change props name in React components?

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I want the consumer of my component to give me this props:

```
<MyComponent
    firstProp='first value'
    secondProp='second value'
/>
```

And I have an internal state inside my component, called `firstProp`.

I know I can either change the name of the internal state, or change the prop name.

But this is a simple example. In reality in our codebase we have a huge dependency and hierarchy of components and it's not easy for us to change names.

I wonder if it's possible that I change the name of `firstProp` I recieve in my component to something else?

Comment: You can alias the prop you wanna rename when destructuring the `props` in your child. See: https://davidwalsh.name/destructuring-alias

Comment: Or just don't destructure `props`, then `props.firstProp` and `firstProp` don't clash at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your consumer component :

```
const {firstProp:yourPrefferedName} = props
```